# Unclear how to connect Plivo to OpenTok Java SDK SIP

Tags: java, sip, opentok, tokbox, plivo

I'm trying to use Plivo with the [OpenTok Java SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK) to dial out. There is an example for javascript where Plivo is used.

I'm able to invoke the method `Openok.dial()` and get a positive response that I then send to my react client.

There are no errors but I'm not calling the targeted number.

I'm not understanding how to use the uris or if they are still necessary.

So is it still necessary to create the uri's as stated in the JS example (https://github.com/opentok/opentok-sip-samples/tree/master/Plivo-SIP-Dial-Out)? And how do i then use those uri's?

Or is there an example i can peek to get a rough idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The [OpenTok SIP Interconnect](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/sip/) feature allows you dial out to a SIP address (uri). With the [Plivo sample](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-sip-samples/tree/master/Plivo-SIP-Dial-Out), you would have to create an application on their website and configure the Plivo application with the appropriate webhooks so when that when you dial out to the Plivo SIP uri from OpenTok, you will get events on the webhook which will allow you to connect the OpenTok session with the PSTN user.

You can also leverage [Nexmo](https://nexmo.com/) or other SIP providers to dial out and connect an OpenTok session with a PSTN user. For example, if you use Nexmo, you can dial directly to a phone number by constructing the [SIP properties](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK#working-with-sip-interconnect) in the [OpenTok Java SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK) like so:

```
String nexmoApiKey = "";
String nexmoApiSecret = "";
String sessionId = "";
String token = "";
SipProperties properties = new SipProperties.Builder()
     .sipUri("sip:15555555555@sip.nexmo.com")
     .from("from@example.com")
     .headersJsonStartingWithXDash(headerJson)
     .userName(nexmoApiKey)
     .password(nexmoApiSecret)
     .secure(false)
     .build();
 Sip sip = opentok.dial(sessionId, token, properties);
```

Please note that you would have to configure the `phoneNumber`, `sessionId`, `token`, and credentials - I've just added a sample number along with empty strings as the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Could you provide more information what should be in the headersJsonStartingWithXDash. Can't find any information.

Comment: Hey Dante, the headers are optional when dialing out with Nexmo. I will update the Java SDK README with an example on how to use the headers :)

Comment: That would be greate, Thanks a lot for the help!